# IOS - Very slow in app purchase in simulator in the sandbox environment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm developing in app purchase functionality for my iphone app. The sandbox environment seems to be very slow, it takes sometimes even more than 30 seconds before the confirmation alert appears and then next 30 seconds or more before I can enter my credentials. 
Is that a normal thing with the sandbox env?

Comment: Perhaps you have slowed animations on ;) cannot say why it is slow otherwise except by bad programming.

Comment: Mine seems slow at times as well, not every time though. How erratic is yours?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus - given StoreKit handles all the networking for IAPs, and that IAPs are inherently modal operations, *and* that the sandbox environment is known to be rather slow on occasion it is probably best not to blindly throw out "bad programming" as a reason.

Comment: Three years later and I'm seeing the same issue. One day sandbox IAPs are blazing fast, the next day (same codebase) they take 1 minute or more. Seems to be an issue on the Apple end.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a little slower than production but not THAT slow.